# Windows grep not working with regexr expression

Tags: regex, windows, grep

Entering this regular expression on [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) extracts `/watch?v=something_until_&` from YouTube playlist site source code.

```
/watch\?v=(?:(?!&).)*
```

For example: `/watch?v=8j1GYEJSQKs`

But entering this as a Windows grep command does not work.

```
grep "/watch\?v=(?:(?!&).)*" source.txt > links.txt
```

I was only to get something similar with this:

```
grep "/watch?v=" source.txt > watch.txt
```

but this outputs the whole line of code in which it finds `/watch?=`

What is different to grep regular expressions than the one on RegExr?

Comment: You can probably use a simpler regex? `/watch\?v=(.*?)&.*`?

Answer (score 3):

grep default uses `BRE`, which means it doesn't support look-behind/ahead.

use `grep -P` and try again, which uses `PCRE`

Comment: Or rewrite the query to not use look aheads, since this is a pretty simple regex.

Comment: grep -P works with the regular expression but also outputs the whole line not stopping at the first "&"

Comment: check @klarki's answer, you need `-o`, if you want to get **only** the matched part. read/search the man page too

Answer (score 2):

to output just the matched parts of the file use `grep -o`

here's the difference:

```
$ echo "test abc test" | grep "a.*c"
test abc test
$ echo "test abc test" | grep -o "a.*c"
abc
```

Comment: grep -P -o "/watch\?v=(?:(?!&).)*" source.txt > watch.txt

Answer (score 1):

Your regex uses an unnecessary negative look ahead, which is not supported by default.

Try this:

```
/watch\?v=[^&]+
```